# Debugger not working in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, blazor

I have upgraded visual studio 2019 to visual studio 2022 to work on .net 6.0 framework (Blazor web application).I am facing Debug issues while hitting break point.Please check below screenshot and advise how to resolve this issues.

[image: Debug Error]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because general help on debugging applications isn't really applicable on this forum

Comment: Hi @Ismail Clean project and rebuild your project again.

Comment: No still not working